# Using session variables in php

Tags: php, html

[image: Click here to view the design page]

I have 2 pages: **index.php** (where I input brand name in a textbox and on clicking submit I need to view the brands I added in drop down box in same page) and **product page** (where I can edit the brands I select in the index page).

I am not using database, instead I'm trying to store value in session variable. I need to know how I can use dynamic session variable so that each time a new brand would be added to drop down menu...

**index.php**

```
<body><div>
<form name="brand" method="post" action="brand_action.php">
Brand Name: <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<div>
<?PHP
if(isset($_SESSION["bname"]))
{?>
<form name="add" action="product.php" method="post">

Brands :<select name="brand" id="brand">
<?PHP
$a=$_SESSION["bname"];
?>
<option value="<?PHP echo($a);?>"> <?PHP echo($a);?> </option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" name="Edit" value="EDIT" />
</form>

<?PHP
    }

?>
</div>

</body>
```

In the index_action.php page,I'm thinking to push each brand into an array and store in session variable and call it in index.php page and put it in drop down list.How can I do it?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Yup, going to need a little code here to help ya out.

Comment: why don't you just do this: $_SESSION["brands"][]=$_POST["brand"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can make a session variable act as an **array**. Store all the brand names in that array, then loop through it.

Here's an example.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_POST['brand']))
{
    $_SESSION['bname'] = array();
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['bname'][] = $_POST['brand'];
}
?>

<body><div>
<form name="brand" method="post" action="s.php">
Brand Name: <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<div>
<?PHP
if(isset($_SESSION["bname"]))
{?>
<form name="add" action="product.php" method="post">

Brands :
<select name="brand" id="brand">
    <?php
    foreach($_SESSION['bname'] as $brand_name)
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?PHP echo($brand_name);?>"> <?PHP echo($brand_name);?> </option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
<input type="submit" name="Edit" value="EDIT" />
</form>

<?PHP
    }

?>
</div>

</body>
```

Also remember, `session_start` should always be the first line of the page in which you need to use sessions.

Comment: Thanks..it works...Could you explain the code.......<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_POST['brand']))
{
    $_SESSION['bname'] = array();
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['bname'][] = $_POST['brand'];
}
?>

Comment: Well we had to use a `session` variable as an array. If I defined it in a normal manner, then whenever the form is submitted, it will overwrite all the values of the session array. Therefore, in order to make `$_SESSION['bname']` as array, I implemented above. Because only for one time `$_POST['brand']` will not be set.